# GameCenter Players' data

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Can I send a message via mail to top players in the leaderboard? 
Is there a way to get the list of their emails?

Comment: I don't thnink Apple would allow emails to be read by 3rd-parties as it's potentially spam-prone.

Comment: but can we send to them?

Comment: If you have an email address, you can use MFMailComposeViewController for sending an email.

Comment: Ok, but do I have these email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Apple will never give a user (or developer) another user's personal information, such as their email address. That would lead to all kinds of abuses and ill will.

You can ask for information in your app and some people will voluntarily give it, although a lot will not. You would have to provide your own server to collect the information; there's no game center function that passes information from the user back to the developer other than game statistics.

If email is the only thing you want I think Apple will approve an app that gives the user some reason to email you then you can use the From: or Reply To: address to communicate back to them. But that would still be voluntary on the part of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email address, you can use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for sending an email. Hope I helped.

Comment: Ok, but is there access through GameCenter to the players' email addresses?

Comment: you COULD always just send them a friend and ask for their email.

Comment: what do you mean by "just send them a friend"?